# HTML forms, add data from another domain

Tags: javascript, forms, cross-domain

I have missed the cross domain waggon, and have just started investigating.

My question is:

Is it possible add data to the eg. input/@name="x" field in domain-a.com/form.html
from domain-b/add.html?

As far as I know it is not possible with JavaScript to write to the domain-a's document from a function in domain-b.

But I think I have seen this has been done (or I have been dreaming).

If I have not been dreaming, does anyone know what kind techniques that have been used to accomplish this?

Thanks for tips, examples and advices in advance,

Kobi

Answer (score 0):

If you own domain-a, you can alter the server side script to set the page elements with the appropriate querystring parameters.

Comment: Sorry, possible bad explaination. I meant with client scripting. Eg.
window.opener.document.forms['my-form'].name.value = 'Hello!';

I know that the document is not read or writable from other domains, I only have limited access to the window.opener.

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway to do that. .... I won't delete my answer in case it helps anybody else who stumbles upon it.